# parallelizing nested for loop with cuda have big limit

Tags: cuda

I am new to CUDA. I'm trying to write a CUDA kernel to perform the following piece of code.

```
for(int oz=0;oz<count1;oz++)
    {
        for(int ox=0;ox<scale+1;ox++)
        {

            for(int xhn=0;xhn<Wjh;xhn++)
            {
                for(int yhn=0;yhn<Wjv;yhn++)
                {
                    //int numx=xhn+ox*Wjh;
                    int numx=oz*(scale+1)*Wjh+ox*Wjh+xhn;
                    int src2=yhn+xhn*Wjv;
                    Ic_real[src2]=Ic_real[src2]+Sr[oz*(scale+1)*Wjv+ox*Wjv+yhn]*Hr_table[numx]-Si[oz*(scale+1)*Wjv+ox*Wjv+yhn]*Hi_table[numx];
                    Ic_img[src2]=Ic_img[src2]+Sr[oz*(scale+1)*Wjv+ox*Wjv+yhn]*Hi_table[numx]+Si[oz*(scale+1)*Wjv+ox*Wjv+yhn]*Hr_table[numx];
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

the value Wjh=1080,Wjv=1920,scale=255;oz>=4.This is what I have currently,but my code can only perform when count1<=4, if oz>4 ,it doesn't work,does anyone know what should I do ? Cheers

```
__global__ void lut_kernel(float *Sr,float *Si,dim3 size,int Wjh,int Wjv,float *vr,float *vi,
                           float *hr,float *hi,float *Ic_re,float *Ic_im)
{     
    __shared__ float cachere[threadPerblock];
    __shared__ float cacheim[threadPerblock];
    int blockId=blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x;
    int cacheIndex=threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    int z=threadIdx.x;
    int x=threadIdx.y;
    int tid1=threadIdx.y*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    //int tid= blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y)  
                     //  + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
    int countnum=0;
    float re=0.0f;
    float im=0.0f;
    float re_value=0.0f;
    float im_value=0.0f;
    if (z<4 && x<256)
    {    

        int src2=z*(scale+1)*Wjh+x*Wjh+blockIdx.y;
        re=Sr[z*(scale+1)*Wjv+x*Wjv+blockIdx.x]*hr[src2]-Si[z*(scale+1)*Wjv+x*Wjv+blockIdx.x]*hi[src2];
        im=Sr[z*(scale+1)*Wjv+x*Wjv+blockIdx.x]*hi[src2]+Si[z*(scale+1)*Wjv+x*Wjv+blockIdx.x]*hr[src2];


        }
       cachere[cacheIndex]=re;
       cacheim[cacheIndex]=im;

       __syncthreads();

       int index=threadPerblock/2;
       while(index!=0)
       {
          if(cacheIndex<index)
          {
              cachere[cacheIndex]+=cachere[cacheIndex+index];
              cacheim[cacheIndex]+=cacheim[cacheIndex+index];
          }
             index/=2;

       }
       if(cacheIndex==0)
       {
         Ic_re[blockId]=cachere[0];
         Ic_im[blockId]=cacheim[0];
         //printf("Ic= %d,blockId= %d\n",Ic_re[blockId],blockId);
       }

    }
```

the kernel parameter is:
dim3 dimBlock(count1,256);
    dim3 dimGrid(Wjv,Wjh);

```
lut_kernel<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_Sr,d_Si,size,Wjh,Wjv,dvr_table,dvi_table,dhr_table,dhi_table,dIc_re,dIc_im);
```

if count1>4,what shuold I do to  parallelize the nested for code?

Comment: CUDA is not related to C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code briefly and it seems that the computation of Ic_img and Ic_real elements is easy to parallelize (**count1**, **scale+1**, **Wjh**, **Wjv** have no dependency at all among each other). Thus, there's no need to have shared variables and while loops in the kernel; it's easy to implement like below, where an extra parameter int numElements = count1 *(scale+1) * Wjh * Wjv.

```
int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
if (i < numElements) {
    //....
}
```

The code will be significantly much easier to maintain and eliminate bugs prone to long codes like your example. If src2 values do not repeat at all in the innermost loop, the performance is close to optimal as well. If 'src2' may repeat, use an expression with 'atomicAdd' so that the results will be correct as expected; with atomicAdd, the performance may not be optimal, but at least one correctly implemented bug free kernel is successfully implemented. If it causes performance bottleneck, then modify it by trying and experimenting some different implementations.